# reading from serial port C#

Tags: c#

I have code reading from serial port randomly, and I want get specific data in specific locations, but the port sending the data line by line continuously, like that

`H91F O69F S124F D-1F H94F O70F S119F D-2F H95F O69F S119F D0F H90F O70F S122F D2F H91F O69F S123F D3F H93F O69F S122F D5F H94F O71F S122F D2F H92F O69F S120F D1F H92F O69F S121F D1F H91F O69F S122F D1F H91F O70F S120F D-2F H95F O73F S121F D-4F H90F O69F S124F D-2F H94F O72F S123F D-3F H90F O70F S119F D-5F H94F O72F S122F D-6F H95F O69F S122F D-9F H90F O69F S123F D-11F`

send line by line from `H` to last `F`

`H91F O69F S124F D-1F` then another line `H94F O70F S119F D-2F`

I need to get the number between each letters like between `H` and `F` and between `O` and `F`, the numbers

```
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

serialPort.Open();
string datasize = serialPort.ReadTo("D");
string firstdata = "";

firstdata = serialPort.ReadExisting();

string data = "";
int firsth = 0;
int firstd = 0;
int lastf = 0;

firsth = firstdata.IndexOf("H");
firstd = firstdata.IndexOf("D" , startIndex: firsth);
lastf = firstdata.IndexOf("F" , startIndex: firstd);
data = firstdata.Substring(firsth, lastf + 1);

// MessageBox.Show(data);

int h = data.IndexOf("H");
int firstF = data.IndexOf("F" , startIndex: h);
string hdata = data.Substring(h + 1, firstF - h - 1);

// string hstring = Regex.Match(hdata, @"\d+").Value;
PulseBox.Text = hdata;

int o = data.IndexOf("O");
int secondF = data.IndexOf("F", startIndex: o);
string odata = data.Substring(o + 1, secondF - o - 1);

//  string ostring = Regex.Match(odata, @"\d+").Value;
OxyBox.Text = odata;

int s = data.IndexOf("S");
int thirdF = data.IndexOf("F" , startIndex: s);
string sdata = data.Substring(s + 1, thirdF - s - 1);

// string sstring = Regex.Match(sdata, @"\d+").Value;
SystolicPressure.Text = sdata;

int d = data.IndexOf("D");
int fourthF = data.IndexOf("F", startIndex: d);
string ddata = data.Substring(d + 1, fourthF - d - 1);

//  string dstring = Regex.Match(data, @"\d+").Value;
DiastolicPressure.Text = ddata;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What exactly is your question? You need to filter output?

Comment: i want to read the data from serial port line by line, each line like that H95F O69F S119F D0F

Comment: What about `S` and `F` or any other combination?

Answer (score 1):

As you are processing a fixed pattern, you should use a regular expression (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference for a reference to regular expressions). In your case this would be:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"H(?<H>[\-\d]+)F O(?<O>[\-\d]+)F S(?<S>[\-\d]+)F D(?<D>[\-\d]+)F");
var input = serialPort.ReadExisting(); // e.g. "H91F O69F S124F D-1F H94F O70F S119F D-2F H95F O69F S119F D0F H90F O70F S122F D2F H91F O69F S123F D3F H93F O69F S122F D5F H94F O71F S122F D2F H92F O69F S120F D1F H92F O69F S121F D1F H91F O69F S122F D1F H91F O70F S120F D-2F H95F O73F S121F D-4F H90F O69F S124F D-2F H94F O72F S123F D-3F H90F O70F S119F D-5F H94F O72F S122F D-6F H95F O69F S122F D-9F H90F O69F S123F D-11F";
```

If you then apply this regex to your input, it will return all matches:

```
var matches = regex.Matches(input);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
  // match.Value will be your complete match, e.g. "H91F O69F S124F D-1F"
  // match.Groups["H"].Value will contain the value for H, e.g. "91"
  // match.Groups["O"].Value will contain the value for O, e.g. "69"
  // match.Groups["S"].Value will contain the value for S, e.g. "124"
  // match.Groups["D"].Value will contain the value for D, e.g. "-1"
}
```

Comment: it is fixed pattern but the numbers change each time a read, it is not the same numbers, what i need this for var input = "H91F O69F S124F D-1F H94F O70F S119F D-2F H95F O69F S119F D0F H90F O70F S122F D2F H91F O69F S123F D3F H93F O69F S122F D5F H94F O71F S122F D2F H92F O69F S120F D1F H92F O69F S121F D1F H91F O69F S122F D1F H91F O70F S120F D-2F H95F O73F S121F D-4F H90F O69F S124F D-2F H94F O72F S123F D-3F H90F O70F S119F D-5F H94F O72F S122F D-6F H95F O69F S122F D-9F H90F O69F S123F D-11F";, this i will read from the serial

Comment: The input is just an example, see my updated answer.